# Googlemaps V2: Add an info window on GeoJsonPolygon

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps, android-maps-v2

I am using geojson files to draw polygon on the map on Android. Now I wanna add info windows on top of this polygons.  I try to use **GeoJsonPolygonStyle** from 
GeoJsonlayer -> getFeature() method to style these polygon with info window.

But It doesnt give me any options like setTitle() and setSnippet() like it offers for **GeoJsonPointStyle** . Any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating LatLong bounds using the geojson co-ordinates and created InfoWindow using that bounds at the center . Hopefully google releases api in upcoming releases.

Answer (score 0):

what about setting an `setOnPolygonClickListener`?

```
getMap().setOnPolygonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener() {
    public void onPolygonClick(Polygon polygon) {
    //show the a pop-up containing information 
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work . because Polygon is part of Map SDK n GeoJson is open source standard and returns *GeoJsonPolygon* as a reference to the polygon on the map.